# LibGDX rotation Bodies issue

Tags: image, rotation, box2d, libgdx, actor

It is hard to explain the problem so I recorded a video in order to illustrate the issue. [[Video here]](http://videobam.com/CFElL)

I have image in box2d objects (bodies). When user drags an actor the body underneath moves too so that images follow physics. When the body is not fully rotated everything works as expected (drag&drop) but when rotation happens the movement goes crazy making that unwanted effect of infinite rotation.

Here's my approach:

**In the constructor:**

```
for(final Brick b : map.list){
        stage.addActor(b.img);
        Vector3 v = new Vector3(b.box.getPosition().x,b.box.getPosition().y,0);
        camera.project(v);

        b.img.setPosition(v.x-b.img.getWidth()*0.5f, v.y-b.img.getHeight()*0.5f);
        b.img.setOrigin(b.img.getWidth()*0.5f, b.img.getHeight()*0.5f);
        b.img.setRotation((float) Math.toDegrees(b.box.getAngle()));


        b.img.addListener((new DragListener() {
            public void touchDragged (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer) {
                float newPosX =b.img.getX() + x;
                float newPosY = b.img.getY() +  y;
                b.img.setPosition(newPosX-b.img.getWidth()*0.5f,newPosY-b.img.getHeight()*0.5f);
                b.box.setTransform(newPosX, newPosY, b.box.getAngle());
           }

        }));
    }
```

Where map.list is a list containing all bodies that can be dragged.

**In the render function:**

```
for(final Brick b : map.list){
            b.img.setVisible(true);
            b.img.setPosition(b.box.getPosition().x-b.img.getWidth()*0.5f, b.box.getPosition().y-b.img.getHeight()*0.5f);
            b.img.setOrigin(b.img.getWidth()*0.5f, b.img.getHeight()*0.5f);
            b.img.setRotation((float) Math.toDegrees(b.box.getAngle()));
        }
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you set the origin for rotation incorrectly.

```
b.img.setOrigin(b.img.getWidth()*0.5f, b.img.getHeight()*0.5f);
```

As long as the bodies aren't rotated at all, everything works fine. Assuming that your bodies position is at the center of the bodies, this should actually be

```
b.img.setOrigin(v.x, v.y);
```

Try to use the Box2dDebugRenderer to quickly check if the bodies are really moving so weird, or whether you just draw the pictures incorrectly.

Comment: `b.img.setPosition(b.box.getPosition().x-b.img.getWidth()*0.5f, b.box.getPosition().y-b.img.getHeight()*0.5f);
   b.img.setOrigin(b.img.getWidth()*0.5f, b.img.getHeight()*0.5f);
   b.img.setRotation((float) Math.toDegrees(b.box.getAngle()));`

This is what I have now and [this](http://videobam.com/RTbAO) is what it does. What is what you call v? I assume it is the body, which for me is b.box. If I do `b.img.setOrigin(b.box.getPosition().x, b.box.getPosition().y);` I get [this](http://videobam.com/STjyr) which is not what I'm looking for. Did I understand you right? Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, yes you got that right. But well, it seems that the image is not the problem, but the body itself behaves so weird. Besides the fact that you do not use any pixel-to-meter conversion here, the code seems to be correct.